# Return from two tables in single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a query that inserts into two tables at once (required because of foreign key constraints linking them) and would like to return the result of both inserts at the same level but I am not sure how that would be done, or if it is even possible.

The inserts look like this and work fine:

```
with org_b as (
    insert into public.base (
        id,
        organisation_id,
        last_modified_by
    )
    values ('<organisation UUID/>', '<organisation UUID/>', '<user UUID/>')
    returning *
), org_eb as (
    insert into public.entity_base (
        id
    )
    values ('<organisation UUID/>')
    returning *
), org as (
    insert into public.organisation_data (
        id, 
        armicus_name
    )
    values ('<organisation UUID/>', 'Stack Overflow')
    returning *
), use_b as (
    insert into public.base (
        id,
        organisation_id,
        last_modified_by
    )
    values ('<user UUID/>', '<organisation UUID/>', '<user UUID/>')
    returning *
), use_eb as (
    insert into public.entity_base (
        id
    )
    values ('<user UUID/>')
    returning *
), use as (
    insert into public.user_account_data (
        id,
        email
    )
    values ('<user UUID/>', 'stack@overflow.com')
    returning *
)
```

What I would like is to return it something like this:

```
select to_json(
    select org_b.id, org_b.organisation_id, org_b.created_date, org_b.last_modified_date, org_b.last_modified_by, org_b.armicus_data, org.armicus_name
    from org_b
    join org on org_b.id = org.id
) as organisation, to_json(
    select use_b.id, use_b.organisation_id, use_b.created_date, use_b.last_modified_date, use_b.last_modified_by, use_b.armicus_data, use.email
    from use_b
    join use on use_b.id = use.id
) as user
from org_b
```

But this throws a syntax error, is there a way to achieve this? I can also upload the SQL to create the tables if that would help.

Edited to add SQL to create tables and constraints:

Create base table:

```
CREATE TABLE base (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    organisation_id uuid NOT NULL,
    created_date timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    last_modified_date timestamptz NOT NUll,
    last_modified_by uuid NOT NULL,
    armicus_data jsonb
);
```

Create entity base:

```
CREATE TABLE entity_base (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES base(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    template_id uuid
);
```

Create organisation data:

```
CREATE TABLE organisation_data (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES entity_base(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    armicus_name TEXT
);
```

Create user account data:

```
CREATE TABLE user_account_data (
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES entity_base(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    email text NOT NULL
);
```

Add organisation id foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE base ADD CONSTRAINT base_organisation_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (organisation_id) REFERENCES organisation_data(id);
```

Add last modified by foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE base ADD CONSTRAINT base_last_modified_by_fkey FOREIGN KEY (last_modified_by) REFERENCES user_account_data(id);
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that's it but try to enclose the subqueries in parenthesis (additionally to the parenthesis enclosing the arguments for `to_json()`). Otherwiese yes, the `CREATE` statements would help, as well  the complete error message you get.

Comment: `select ... from (a join b on ...)`

Comment: Your problem statement mentions two inserts but the code has six.  I'm confused.

Comment: @stickybit the error message for the sql I attempted just said syntax error at the select inside the first to_json

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Your problem is a code extension not returning what you expect. Wait until that's solved to ask re your overall goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem of missing column names with this:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT to_json(o)
    FROM (
        SELECT org_b.id, org_b.organisation_id, org_b.created_date, org_b.last_modified_date, org_b.last_modified_by, org_b.armicus_data, org.armicus_name
        FROM org_b
        JOIN org on org_b.id = org.id
    ) o
) AS organisation, (
    SELECT to_json(u)
    FROM (
        SELECT use_b.id, use_b.organisation_id, use_b.created_date, use_b.last_modified_date, use_b.last_modified_by, use_b.armicus_data, use.email
        FROM use_b
        JOIN use on use_b.id = use.id
    ) u     
) AS user
FROM org_b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase this as:

```
select to_json( (select b.id, b.organisation_id, b.created_date, b.last_modified_date, b.last_modified_by, b.armicus_data, org.armicus_name
                 from org_b b join
                      org o
                      on b.id = o.id
                )
              ) as organisation,
       to_json( (select b.id, b.organisation_id, b.created_date, b.last_modified_date, b.last_modified_by, b.armicus_data, u.email
                 from use_b b join
                      use u
                      on b.id = u.id
                )
              ) as user
from org_b ;
```

Or I would probably write this moving the json conversion to the subquery:

```
select (select to_json( (b.id, b.organisation_id, b.created_date, b.last_modified_date, b.last_modified_by, b.armicus_data, org.armicus_name) )
        from org_b b join
             org o
             on b.id = o.id
       ) as organisation,
      (select to_json( (b.id, b.organisation_id, b.created_date, b.last_modified_date, b.last_modified_by, b.armicus_data, u.email) )
       from use_b b join
            use u
            on b.id = u.id
      ) ) as user
from org_b
```

Comment: The first throws a syntax error on the as at the end of the first to_json (as organisation). The second one works but the JSON keys are all f1 to f7 instead of the column names, is there a way to tell it what to call the properties?